# JQuery function uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

I hate to ask such a basic question, but I am having a hard time finding solid examples online. I'm green to all of this.

I have the following HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" >
  $(function (Function1() {
   alert('Hello from JavaScript!');
  }));
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <button onclick="Function1()">
        Click me!
    </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I receive the following error in the chrome console on click:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Function1 is not defined

It has to be something obvious, but I don't know why my function call isn't working. I must have some kind of JQuery specific syntax wrong.

Comment: Well, it definitely isn't working; I'll give you that :)

Comment: I recommend reading http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: Could you recommend a good reference for function calls? Simple examples would be most helpful

Comment: Try reading "JavaScript: The Good Parts" (you can find it on Amazon or anywhere really).

Comment: I recommend [Getting Started (JavaScript Tutorial)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Getting_Started)

Comment: I'll try to look them all up :) Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowCreeper That's a good book but not for JavaScript beginners!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fix for your issue: Your syntax was wrong.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Function1() {
            alert('Hello from JavaScript!');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button onclick="Function1()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

You could just create a click handler instead.

Example:-

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVBYx/)

```
$(function(){

    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
     alert('Hello from JavaScript!');
    })
})
```